# Oracle replace a word in the middle

Tags: sql, string, oracle

`fse.name = ASD-122-XXX` and `fn.name = ASD-125-FFF`

I want to put all `fn.name` the 122 of the `fse.name` associate to the `fse.name`

I have this but it doesn't work the way I want

```
var_rama VARCHAR2;

Begin
FOR var in (select fse.name ,fn.name as nombreFnode, fn.descr 
            from fiberspliceenclosure_lt fse 
            inner join segments seg
                on fse.mslink = seg.link1
            inner join fibernode fn
                on fn.mslink = seg.link2
            where fse.name like 'CO905%'
            and fn.descr like '04-%')
LOOP
  var.(substr(fse.name,7,5)) := var_rama;
  replace (substr (fn.name,7,5), var_rama);


END LOOP;
```

Comment: Please to not spam caps.

Comment: Would you please provide sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try with INSTR function to find out whether your finding string is there in you destination variable or not? if its there then just use REPLACE to replace the string with your desire string. I guess, this would work for you..because every time you dont need to find the position of your search string.

As per my understanding, he want to replace 122 from fse.name with fn.name string. so below is my code for that.
    Declare
    v_instr number;
    v_out varchar2(50);
    begin
    for i in (sql_query) loop
    v_instr := instr(i.fse_name,'122');
    if v_instr >0 then
    v_out := replace(i.fse_name,'122',i.fn_name);
    end if;
    end loop;
    end;

Comment: Did you forget to press *Save*?

Answer (score 0):

If your names are always in the same format i.e. `AAA-999-AAA` this is fairly simple with just `substr()` calls:

```
select substr(fn.name, 1, 4) 
       || substr(fse.name, 5, 3) 
       || substr(fn.name, 8) as new_name
from fn
     join fse on fn.id = fse.id
/
```

However, if the name formats can vary - say `AAAA-99-AAAAA` is valid - then we can't use fixed offsets. So the code becomes more complicated, with `instr()` calls to identify the position of each dash:

```
select substr(fn.name, 1, instr(fn.name, '-', 1, 1)) 
       || substr(fse.name, instr(fse.name, '-', 1, 1)+1, instr(fse.name, '-', 1, 2) - instr(fse.name, '-', 1, 1)-1 )
       || substr(fn.name, instr(fn.name, '-', 1, 2)) as new_name
from fn
     join fse on fn.id = fse.id
/
```

No doubt there is a snazzier solution using regular expressions but I prefer to avoid regex for tasks which can be done with `substr()` and `instr()` for performance reasons.